# Finding at least one common node in two lists with different lengths

Tags: algorithm, list

As the title says, I'm looking for an efficient (not best) way to find a common node (one is enough) in two lists.

What we know about the lists is, we have 2 lists with different lengths and somewhere they got a common node. From the point where the common node is, both lists merge so they accord with each other from this point.

I haven't written down the code and I won't because first I need to be sure if my way will work. What makes me unsure is step 4:

1. Find out the length of the first list.
2. Find out the length of the second list.
3. Take the bigger list and subtract it with the smaller list (I call the solution x).
4. Take the longer list and run through the first node to the x-th node
   ==> both lists should (!) have same number of nodes.
5. Now we can run through both lists simultaneously till we found the common node.

Do you think it's ready to be coded? :)

Comment: If both lists agree with each other from a certain point, just walk both lists in reverse until they diverge?

Comment: Your approach is a good one if they are singly linked lists.

Comment: ^
Yeah they are singly linked lists.
By the way, your idea with reverse is very interesting, thanks for sharing it!